# Get x,y style coordinates for pandas data object

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if it is possible to search for a value in a pandas dataframe and if it is found, return row, column name style coordinates. For example, if searching the dataframe below for the string of `mat`, (3, C) would be returned.

```
     A    B    C
0   20     32  bat
1   30    234  cat
2   10     23  rat
3   40     23  mat
4   50  42523  etc
```

I have read through the documentation and the closest solution I've found is the `index.get_loc()` though this only returns `loc` based on a named index.

pandas version 0.22.0

Comment: check np.where ~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Wen suggested, `np.where` is an efficient way to search for coordinates for values. The below method will return a list of such coordinates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[20, 32, 'bat'], [30, 234, 'cat'],
                  [10, 23, 'rat'], [40, 23, 'mat'],
                  [50, 42523, 'etc']], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

[(x, df.columns[y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(df.values == 'mat'))]  # [(3, 'C')]
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain what *np.where actually do ? Tried to search around but still not very clear about it. Would appreciate for detailed explanations. @jpp

Comment: @ChauLoi, I can't explain it better than the [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which also includes example usage.

Comment: I mean the star (*) before the np.where @jpp

Comment: @ChauLoi, That's the unpacking operator, see [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpacking#unpacking-argument-lists) for an explanation and example.